# How to instantiate node progammatically in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am currently creating basic project, in which I want to instantiate a GUI progammatically. The scene has a TextureRect node, which has the following script attached:

```
extends TextureRect
var texture = preload("res://some_texture.png")

@onready var inner_rect: TextureRect = TextureRect.new()
@onready var outer_rect: TextureRect = self

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    print("SCRIPT READY")

    inner_rect.set_name("InnerRect")
    
    inner_rect.set_texture(texture)
    get_parent().add_child(inner_rect)
    inner_rect.set_owner(get_parent())
    inner_rect.set_z_index(2)
    
    outer_rect.set_z_index(1)
    
    print(outer_rect)
    print(inner_rect)
    print(inner_rect.texture.width)
    print(inner_rect.scale)
    print(inner_rect.visible)   

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(_delta):
    pass
```

No matter what I tried, I can't get this new node that I instantiate in the code (InnerRect) to show. Width is right (20px), scale is (1, 1), visibility is true, but it simply won't show up in the scene, nor in the scene viewer. I tried turning the visibility of OuterRect off to see if it is behind it, but is not. Any idea why this happens?

Edit: After further testing it seems that the node does not get attached to the parent scene. Changing it to be added as a child to inner_rect works, and displays the image after loading. However this has the effect of moving the inner_rect whenever the outer_rect moves, which is not what I want. How could I make it so that inner_rect can become the child of the scene?

Comment: Godot version 3 or 4? Do you get any errors? Also did you check the type of "texture" variable to see if its an Image or an actual texture, if its an image you need to convert it to a texture.

Comment: Do you want it to show in the editor? As written, this script is not set to run in the editor, only on the running game.

Comment: @Theraot Yes I meant in the game. Whenever it is ran it does not show up.

Comment: @unlut Seems that the type of texture is CompressedTexture2D. I am not sure how I should attach an image to be the default sprite of an object.

Comment: If you want it to become a child of the root of a scene then you could try get_tree().root.add_child()